# Multiscene editing: Game window shows inactive scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have loaded 2 scenes using Multi-Scene Editing.

Scene "SampleScene" features a woman.
Scene "Inventory" features a suitcase.

As one can see in the screenshot, "SampleScene" is not the active scene.
"inventoryScene" is the active scene (one can see that by the fact that "Set Active Scene" is greyed out).

Why does the game window show the "SampleScene" anyways?

I expected the game window to look like the camera preview on the right bottom (which shows a suitcase with a weapon in it).

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active scene doesn't actually change what is rendered. If the wrong thing is rendering, it's because you have multiple cameras and the depths are set incorrectly.

If you want to have inventoryScene be the scene that is drawn, the camera in that scene needs to have a higher depth than the one in SampleScene.

Sources: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-depth.html

Comment: I haven't started the game yet. Does your answer apply anyways? I expected the game window to look like the camera preview on the right bottom (which shows a suitcase with a weapon in it).

Comment: This applies whether you are in play mode or not.

Comment: I seem to be blind. I don't see "Depth" in the Inspector for the camera.

Comment: Ah, I found it under Camera->Output Settings->Depth. Thank you!